# Why is Entity Framework adding so much onto my query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an IQueryable that I'm building up.  When I run it through Entity Framework, it takes 2.5 seconds to run.  When I grab the query and run it, or just profiling the database and seeing the query that EF runs, it takes < 100ms.  What is EF doing for those other 2.49 seconds and how do I stop it from taking so long?

I've tried AsNoTracking(), turning LazyLoadingEnabled off...

EDIT: Running a stopwatch against results.ToString() takes just as long as running the query itself (even running .ToString() 2x in a row) so it looks like I need to reduce the time taken to generate the query itself.

Query, as seen by SQL profiler. Latest execution time, 87ms:

```
SELECT 
[Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project3].[loan_number] AS [loan_number], 
[Project3].[cifno] AS [cifno], 
[Project3].[cifnumber] AS [cifnumber], 
[Project3].[curr_maturity_date] AS [curr_maturity_date], 
[Project3].[total_past_due_balance] AS [total_past_due_balance], 
[Project3].[userdef02] AS [userdef02], 
[Project3].[userdef05] AS [userdef05], 
[Project3].[transaction_amount] AS [transaction_amount], 
[Project3].[user_reference] AS [user_reference], 
[Project3].[effective_date] AS [effective_date], 
[Project3].[userdef03] AS [userdef03], 
[Project3].[userdef01] AS [userdef01], 
[Project3].[acctrefno] AS [acctrefno], 
[Project3].[userdef04] AS [userdef04], 
[Project3].[transrefno] AS [transrefno], 
[Project3].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project3].[paid_date] AS [paid_date], 
[Project3].[check_number] AS [check_number], 
[Project3].[transaction_amount1] AS [transaction_amount1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter1].[transrefno] AS [transrefno], 
    [Filter1].[acctrefno1] AS [acctrefno], 
    [Filter1].[effective_date] AS [effective_date], 
    [Filter1].[transaction_amount] AS [transaction_amount], 
    [Filter1].[user_reference] AS [user_reference], 
    [Filter1].[userdef01] AS [userdef01], 
    [Filter1].[userdef03] AS [userdef03], 
    [Filter1].[userdef04] AS [userdef04], 
    [Filter1].[userdef05] AS [userdef05], 
    [Extent6].[loan_number] AS [loan_number], 
    [Extent9].[cifno] AS [cifno], 
    [Extent13].[cifnumber] AS [cifnumber], 
    [Extent16].[curr_maturity_date] AS [curr_maturity_date], 
    [Extent19].[total_past_due_balance] AS [total_past_due_balance], 
    [Extent23].[userdef02] AS [userdef02], 
    [Extent46].[paid_date] AS [paid_date], 
    [Extent50].[check_number] AS [check_number], 
    [Limit21].[transaction_amount] AS [transaction_amount1], 
    1 AS [C1], 
     CAST( [Filter1].[transaction_code] AS int) AS [C2]
    FROM                                (SELECT [Extent3].[transrefno] AS [transrefno], [Extent3].[acctrefno] AS [acctrefno1], [Extent3].[transaction_code] AS [transaction_code], [Extent3].[effective_date] AS [effective_date], [Extent3].[transaction_amount] AS [transaction_amount], [Extent3].[user_reference] AS [user_reference], [Extent3].[userdef01] AS [userdef01], [Extent3].[userdef02] AS [userdef02], [Extent3].[userdef03] AS [userdef03], [Extent3].[userdef04] AS [userdef04], [Extent3].[userdef05] AS [userdef05]
        FROM   [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[cif] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[cifno] = [Extent2].[cifno]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[acctrefno] = [Extent3].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[cifnumber] IN ('647077')) AND ([Extent3].[userdef03] IN ('sizt7c2IokaTKwQCbdXyaw==', '2VnYfyKBwESZtVhXdXxfXg==', 'sizt7c2IokaTKwQCbdXyaw==', 'sizt7c2IokaTKwQCbdXyaw==', '9CR/EFNaFUqPEx3V/WRVww==')) AND ([Extent3].[userdef03] IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Filter1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent4].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent4]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[acctrefno] = [Extent5].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent5].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent4].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent4].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent6] ON [Filter1].[acctrefno1] = [Extent6].[acctrefno]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent7].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent7]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent7].[acctrefno] = [Extent8].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent8].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent7].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent7].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit2]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent9] ON [Filter1].[acctrefno1] = [Extent9].[acctrefno]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent10].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent10]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent10].[acctrefno] = [Extent11].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent11].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent10].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent10].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit3]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent12] ON [Filter1].[acctrefno1] = [Extent12].[acctrefno]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[cif] AS [Extent13] ON [Extent12].[cifno] = [Extent13].[cifno]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent14].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent14]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent14].[acctrefno] = [Extent15].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent15].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent14].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent14].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit4]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent16] ON [Filter1].[acctrefno1] = [Extent16].[acctrefno]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent17].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent17]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent18] ON [Extent17].[acctrefno] = [Extent18].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent18].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent17].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent17].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit5]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent19] ON [Filter1].[acctrefno1] = [Extent19].[acctrefno]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent20].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent20]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent21] ON [Extent20].[acctrefno] = [Extent21].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent21].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent20].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent20].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit6]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent22] ON [Filter1].[acctrefno1] = [Extent22].[acctrefno]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct_detail] AS [Extent23] ON [Extent22].[acctrefno] = [Extent23].[acctrefno]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent24].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent24]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent25] ON [Extent24].[acctrefno] = [Extent25].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent25].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent24].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent24].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit7]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent26].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent26]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent27] ON [Extent26].[acctrefno] = [Extent27].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent27].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent26].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent26].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit8]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent28].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent28]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent29] ON [Extent28].[acctrefno] = [Extent29].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent29].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent28].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent28].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit9]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent30].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent30]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent31] ON [Extent30].[acctrefno] = [Extent31].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent31].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent30].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent30].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit10]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent32].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent32]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent33] ON [Extent32].[acctrefno] = [Extent33].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent33].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent32].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent32].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit11]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent34].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent34]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent35] ON [Extent34].[acctrefno] = [Extent35].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent35].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent34].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent34].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit12]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent36].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent36]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent37] ON [Extent36].[acctrefno] = [Extent37].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent37].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent36].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent36].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit13]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent38].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent38]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent39] ON [Extent38].[acctrefno] = [Extent39].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent39].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent38].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent38].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit14]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent40].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent40]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent41] ON [Extent40].[acctrefno] = [Extent41].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent41].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent40].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent40].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit15]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent42].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent42]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent43] ON [Extent42].[acctrefno] = [Extent43].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent43].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent42].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent42].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit16]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent44].[voucher_id] AS [voucher_id]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent44]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent45] ON [Extent44].[acctrefno] = [Extent45].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent45].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent44].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent44].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit17]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[voucher] AS [Extent46] ON [Limit17].[voucher_id] = [Extent46].[voucher_id]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent47].[voucher_id] AS [voucher_id]
        FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent47]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent48] ON [Extent47].[acctrefno] = [Extent48].[acctrefno]
        WHERE ([Extent48].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent47].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent47].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit18]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[voucher] AS [Extent49] ON [Limit18].[voucher_id] = [Extent49].[voucher_id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[disbursement_check] AS [Extent50] ON [Extent49].[check_id] = [Extent50].[check_id]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Filter21].[transaction_amount], [Filter21].[userdef02], [Filter21].[transrefno1]
        FROM   (SELECT [Extent51].[transaction_amount] AS [transaction_amount], [Extent51].[userdef02] AS [userdef02], [Project1].[transrefno] AS [transrefno1]
            FROM   [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent51]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent52] ON [Extent51].[acctrefno] = [Extent52].[acctrefno]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT TOP (1) 
                [Extent53].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
                FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent53]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent54] ON [Extent53].[acctrefno] = [Extent54].[acctrefno]
                WHERE ([Extent54].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent53].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent53].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Project1] ON 1 = 1
            WHERE ([Extent52].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND ([Extent51].[transaction_code] IN (cast(1000 as decimal(18)), cast(1202 as decimal(18)))) ) AS [Filter21]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent55].[transrefno] AS [transrefno]
            FROM  [dbo].[loanacct_trans_history] AS [Extent55]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[loanacct] AS [Extent56] ON [Extent55].[acctrefno] = [Extent56].[acctrefno]
            WHERE ([Extent56].[cifno] IN (cast(309 as decimal(18)), cast(641 as decimal(18)), cast(60583 as decimal(18)))) AND (([Extent55].[userdef02] = [Filter1].[userdef02]) OR (([Extent55].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[userdef02] IS NULL))) ) AS [Project2] ON 1 = 1
        WHERE ([Filter21].[userdef02] = (CASE WHEN ([Filter21].[transrefno1] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE  CAST( [Project2].[transrefno] AS nvarchar(max)) END)) OR (([Filter21].[userdef02] IS NULL) AND (CASE WHEN ([Filter21].[transrefno1] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE  CAST( [Project2].[transrefno] AS nvarchar(max)) END IS NULL)) ) AS [Limit21]
)  AS [Project3]
ORDER BY [Project3].[effective_date] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

The main part of the query... calling ToList() takes 2.5s

```
            var queryable = ApplyQuery(query, nlsContext);
            var transactionQueryable = queryable.SelectMany(l => l.loanacct_trans_history);

            if (query.UserIds != null)
            {
                var encodedUserIds = query.UserIds.Select(u => GuidEncoder.Encode(u)).ToList();
                transactionQueryable = transactionQueryable.Where(t => encodedUserIds.Contains(t.userdef03));
            }

            if(query.AdvancesOnly)
            {
                transactionQueryable = transactionQueryable.Where(t => AdvanceTypes.Contains(t.transaction_code));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.SortProperty))
            {
                transactionQueryable = ApplySort(nlsContext, transactionQueryable, query);
            }
            else
            {
                transactionQueryable = transactionQueryable.ApplySort(t => t.transaction_reference_no, true);
            }

            transactionQueryable = transactionQueryable.ApplyPaging(query);

            var results = transactionQueryable
                .Select(t => new
                {
                    t,
                    DealerTransaction = nlsContext.loanacct_trans_history
                        .Where(dth => dealerIds.Contains(dth.loanacct.cif.cifno))
                        .Where(dth => dth.userdef02 == t.userdef02)
                        .FirstOrDefault()
                })
                .Select(o => new TransactionHistoryResult
                {
                    Loan = new Loan
                    {
                        AccountNumber = o.t.loanacct.loan_number,
                        ContactId = o.t.loanacct.cifno,
                        ContactNumber = o.t.loanacct.cif.cifnumber,
                        MaturityDate = o.t.loanacct.curr_maturity_date,
                        PastDue = o.t.loanacct.total_past_due_balance,
                        ProgramIdString = o.t.loanacct.loanacct_detail.userdef02,
                    },
                    Transaction = new Transaction
                    {
                        AdminUserId = o.t.userdef05,
                        Amount = o.t.transaction_amount,
                        Comment = o.t.user_reference,
                        EffectiveDate = o.t.effective_date,
                        EncodedUserId = o.t.userdef03,
                        InvoiceNumber = o.t.userdef01,
                        LoanId = o.t.acctrefno,
                        Product = o.t.userdef04,
                        RowId = o.t.transrefno,
                        Type = (Raf.Models.Lending.TransactionType)(int)o.t.transaction_code
                    },
                    PaidDate = o.DealerTransaction.voucher.paid_date,
                    CheckNumber = o.DealerTransaction.voucher.disbursement_check.check_number,
                    CreditServiceFee = nlsContext.loanacct_trans_history
                                    .Where(csfth => CreditServiceFeeTypes.Contains(csfth.transaction_code))
                                    .Where(csfth => dealerIds.Contains(csfth.loanacct.cif.cifno))
                                    .Where(th => th.userdef02 == o.DealerTransaction.transrefno.ToString())
                                    .FirstOrDefault()
                                    .transaction_amount
                });
```

Comment: Is it the very first query you are running against the DB? EF has some large one time startup costs it does once per AppDomain that only happen after you do your very first "touch" of the db.

Comment: Thats one downside to using EF. It's easy for you, but you lose control. This is one thing you lose, performance.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The times are all from calls after the first

Comment: Profile your database, that way you can see what is actually being sent to it.

Comment: @DavidG As I said in my question, I did profile it, and it takes about 10ms to run even when being called by EF.

Comment: Do you have the execution plans to go along with this queries though?

Comment: @DavidG Yes.  Does that matter?  If the DB is handling the query plan, and is also returning the results in 10 ms, then what does the query plan matter?  Please correct any invalid assumptions I'm making.

Comment: How about some code for this query?

Comment: Please show us the actual Entity Framework query, and the SQL query that is being generated from it.

Comment: Did you try to run the query with the same user you have set in  EF connection string? may be is a query plan matter

Comment: @BradleyUffner I've added the code in there.  I can't really add the entire code that generates the query to this single post.

Comment: @MadMyche Added

Comment: @GhiniAntonio The query itself takes 82ms

Comment: How many records are we talking about here?  How many rows?  Also, looking at your query, I see at least 5 different queries and sub-queries involved here, which specifically is the one that is causing the problem?  You just say "the main part", whatever that is.  It's also not clear whether you're running into N+1 issues here.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch This is a single query that gets called, so no, no N+1 issues.  These queries are not the problem.  This whole select statement takes virtually no time.

Comment: @KyleW - It's not a single query that you've shown.  There is a .ToList() for UserId's, then there's a FirstOrDefault() on the CreditServiceFee (That sub-query will get called once for each row), Then there's a subquery on DealerTransaction.  Notice that there's no DealerTransaction or CreditServiceFee in the SQL you posted.  That's because those queries are performed separately by EF.  What's more, you seem to be getting the information for CreditServiceFee and DealerTransaction from a separate EF context.  Which implies a different database.  That also complicates the assembly of the data.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch You're right, the UserId is a separate query.  It's assembled separately and just the parameter to this query.  I'm trying to show only what is part of the stuff that takes time, but I seem to be missing things.  At the time the final ToList is called for that query, only one query is run on the database.  The subqueries are just that, subqueries.  Not separate calls.  The CSF and DealerTransaction are from the same context (`nlsContext`).

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch See my edit.  Running .ToString() on the IQueryable takes just as long as running the query, so in what ways can I reduce the time to generate that query?

Comment: @KyleW - I would suggest trying to simplify the query for testing purposes (not for production purposes).  For instance, removing the subqueries to see how that affects performance.  Keep removing stuff until the performance improves, than start adding it back.

Answer (score 0):

> "When I grab the query and run it"

When you run the query from Sql Server Management Studio, you are using its defaults Query Execution settings, and not necessarily will be the same settings used by entity framework (ado.net).

In Sql Manager you can check the defaults setting under

> Tools/Option/Query Execution/SQL Server

So, if you want to correctly evaluate the query you need to grab the connection settings from the profiler and set that same options to the query when executed from sql management studio.

Comment: Using a profiler won't correctly evaluate the query?

Comment: @Kylew Sql Profiler can evaluate the query within Sql. It is how C#, LINQ, & EF try and figure out how to write the SQL, and then how to assemble it once it receives the data that is slowing you down

Comment: @MadMyche I agree, which is what I'm trying to find out.  This answer says that I need to test the query with a different connection string, which wouldn't affect it

Comment: Not really, it is more of trying to get the connection string and parameters to be the same that Query Profiler is running; there is a lot more to the way a connection and command are setup than DS, UN, & PW.

I'd still prefer to get as much of this out of LINQ and into a View or SP as possible,

Answer (score 0):

The next step after Query execution is Object Materialization, in which Table data retrieved from SQL is converted into individual objects.

SQL will send a big table of lots of repeated values, and SQL will send it fast, probably in same time as when you request raw sql against Sql server, but EF's materialization is slow and it becomes slower and slower with many nested selects.

Since your query's select has nested selects, this will take time as EF will have to perform in memory group by and perform some in memory query to build objects in the graph format you have requested.

And when you say query is 82ms, profiling your C# code will reveal where it is spending most of its time.

Things like `.GroupBy(q => 0)` is performance killer, because EF will not be able to translate this as SQL group by but it will perform in memory group by due to lot of complex statements ahead.

In such case, we can simply create a view and/or stored procedure to create simple table which can map to simple properties in one entity. EF is not designed and is not recommended to be an alternative of stored procedure and power of SQL.

Comment: Thank you.  The GroupBy in that code is actually run separately from the query in question and returns quickly.  I'm removing that part of the code since it's not involved.  I will try profiling the C# code and see how far I can drill down with that.  You mention the nested selects, but that seems to be run by the database just fine and there is no grouping in that.  Would grouping still be done client-side, even with the groupby in my current example not being part of this query?

Comment: I'm all for creating the SP or View and letting EF access that... Letting EF lose with queries like this especially in a 'code-first' environment is like letting FrontPage build your database access on a website

Comment: @MadMyche - I disagree.  EF queries can be very efficient, but you often need to understand how it works internally to build efficient queries.  A lot of people try to build their queries like they would SQL and that doesn't always turn out well.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I disagree, EF is not efficient. Any profiling tool will tell you that.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet - The point went completely over your head.  Yes, any profiling tool will tell you that an inefficiently constructed EF query will be inefficient.  Duh.

Comment: Group by isn't necessary a sql group by, but nested select is kind of group by where your outer select is group of inner rows. And EF takes time to construct.